# How to get the last episode of each series in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structure:

```
id | series_id | season | episode
```

The table represents a TV shows episodes.

I want to fetch the last episode of each series_id.

Example:

```
id | series_id | season | episode
1       1          1         9
2       1          2         1
3       2          1         1
4       2          1         2
```

Wanted result:

```
series_id | season | episode
    1          2         1
    2          1         2
```

I tried the following query which doesn't work, probably because it groups it first, then orders the results.

```
SELECT      series_id, season, episode
FROM        episodes
GROUP BY    series_id
ORDER BY    season DESC, episode DESC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that there's a reasonable max on the number of episodes per season (say, no more than 1000 episodes) you can use a little mathematical trick:

```
SELECT
    series_id
,   MAX(1000*season + episode)/1000 AS season
,   MAX(1000*season + episode)%1000 as episode
FROM episodes
GROUP BY series_id
```

The idea is to construct a value in which incrementing `season` number has priority over the highest `episode` of the prior season, and give these numbers to the `MAX` for selection. In your example the composite numbers would be as follows:

```
id | series_id | season | episode   |  composite
1       1          1         9         1009
2       1          2         1         2001
3       2          1         1         1001
4       2          1         2         1002
```

Once we have our `max`, we use the number of thousands as the season number, and the rest as the episode number.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `group by`.  You want a filter.  Here is one method:

```
select e.*
from episodes e
where (e.season, e.episode) = (select e2.season, e2.episode
                               from episodes e2
                               where e2.series = e.series
                               order by e2.season desc, e2.episode desc
                               limit 1
                              );
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great, but the solution of @dasblinkenlight is working faster.

Comment: Try putting an index on `episodes(series, season, episode)`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select series_id, max(season) as season, max(episode) as episode 
from your_table
group by series_id
```

working sample [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21549/15)

Comment: That will just output the highest season and episode for each series, but that's not what I want. Let's say `S02E01` is the last episode, but there's `S01E22` I want the result to be `S02E01` and not `S02E22`.

Comment: I agree, but as shown in your question is that all columns are integer so in that case this will work, however if values are varchar  then that would not work as expected

Comment: They are indeed integers, I wrote it that way for convenience. You can even see this in your example: for `series_id` 1 you get season 2 and episode 9, although this episode doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Rank` to define results in a set and the filter on your rank.

```
SELECT X.* FROM
(Select *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARATITION BY ID ORDER BY EPISODE DESC)AS RNK
) AS X
WHERE X.RNK = 1
```